# How to get an image of a div using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to use `html2canvas` to get an image of a div to the clipboard so that a user is able to then paste the image in an email or message chat. I've looked up multiple different ways of trying to do this but none of them are working for me.

The code I am using is below.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".canvas-button", function (){
    var div = document.getElementById($(this).data("div"));
    var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = rect.width;
    canvas.height = rect.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.translate(-rect.left,-rect.top);

    html2canvas(div, {
        canvas:canvas,
        height:rect.height,
        width:rect.width,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var image = canvas.toDataURL("impage/png");
            window.open(image);
            var pHtml = "<img src="+image+" />";
            $("#parent").append(pHtml);
        }
    });
});
```

This code is able to find the div but it doesn't give me the image of it. I'm not sure what to do from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks OK on first glance, maybe the coordinates are wrong? Do you need `translate`? You can try hard-coding the left, top, width, height values just to see if it works.

Comment: Or maybe just pass the actual div using only `var div = document.getElementById("yourid");`. Can you post the actual div too?

Comment: unfortunately the actual div id is created in a outside function. so I don't know the hard coded version.

Comment: That may he related to your problem though.